# Is there is a way to register microservice with domain name to netflix eureka?

Tags: java, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-netflix

I am facing a problem with eureka configuration - is it possible to register app service in eureka by domain name like "https://www.google.com" (passed for example to properties via ENV variable) instead of ip address (I am using PAAS where deployments has not got static ip addresses) or hostname (where usually it is the name of the supplier) ?

I tried set eureka

```
preferIpAddress=false
```

or

```
hostname={$HOST}
```

but it does not do what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem with setting eureka.instance.hostname (i.e. google.com) to raw domain page and eureka.instance.nonSecurePort (in my case to 80)